# Weird problems in textarea

Tags: javascript

Well, I have two textareas. When a user will type in one textarea, it will appear in the second textarea simultaneously. So my codes below:

```
<script>
function type () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code');
    code.innerHTML = text;
}
</script>

<textarea cols="20" rows="20" id="text" onKeyUp="type();"></textarea>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" id="code"></textarea>
```

And nothing is written to the second one... Help!

Comment: What is the problem here? That is precisely what your code is going to do.

Comment: exact but nothing is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `value` property, rather than `innerHTML`, of the second textarea.

=== EDIT ===

And `type` is a reserved word in JavaScript and you should not use it as a function name.

Comment: I removed the innerHTML, and it is not working by inserting "value" in place of innerHtml...

Comment: and `type` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Comment: Ya you are right, it is working right now... By the way, I am making a simple text editor, can I remove the second textarea to put an IFrame? The preview will be the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function type () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code');
    code.value = text; // this is the change
}
</script>
```

use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: for the Iframe, if I have understood well, I will have to use Document.write, right? Assuming the second textarea is an IFrame, the code will be like this then:

`code`
<script>
function type () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code');
    code.contentdocument.write = text;
}
</script>
`code`

Comment: if it is an iFrame you should do it like this: `document.getElementById('externaliframe').src="javascript:void( document.writeln("Added html contetnt!") );";' read more about it here http://thetechnofreak.com/technofreak/modify-iframe-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue with the function name nothing other than that.

Comment: for the Iframe, if I have understood well, I will have to use Document.write, right? Assuming the second textarea is an IFrame, the code will be like this then:


<script>
function type () {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    var code = document.getElementById('code');
    code.contentdocument.write = text;
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code. This works fine

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function type1 () {

    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

    var code = document.getElementById("code");
    code.value = text;
}
</script>
<body>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" id="text" onkeyup="type1()"></textarea>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" id="code"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes. Another thing you need to notice that you are using single quotation in line var text = document.getElementById('text').value. There you need to use double quotation like "text". Same in "code".